ArgoCD mono-repo: how to determine which cluster/argocd-server I'm on
We're currently setting up argocd and we're trying to use one repository only for the configuration of all our clusters. This will just be a configuration-Repository containing value-Files and kustomize templates.
The idea is to create one bootrap-app which then triggers a cascade of applications using applicationsets and git-generator. The problem we have is: we don't know on which argo-server/stage we're on. We basically have 3 directories for each configuration/stage. And we need to tell the generator which directory to generate on.
Each cluster hast it's own argocd-instance and we don't have a centralized argocd instance where we can manage this from.
Is there a way to set some sort of global environment variable or the server-name in argocd and then access it directly from within the applicationset?
Example Folder Structure:
|   app.yaml
└───tools
│   │└─example-app
│   │|───app.yaml
│   │|───stage1_values.yaml
│   │|───stage2_values.yaml

thanks in advance

I'm still unclear on your repository layout, but it seems as if each cluster would have a top-level applicationset in which you would use the git generator with a cluster-specific directory path in spec.generators.git.directories.

Each cluster will have a main app we apply manually. The main-app will then generate an applicationset with a git generator which iterates over the directories like tools (helm-charts), subscriptions (operators) and others. In each of this directory is an app.yaml which then creates new applicationsets to go further down the directory tree. At the end of the tree we have our configurations (e.g. value-files) for our stages. And somehow we need to know which config to take. So in my applicationset i need to find out which cluster I'm on. hope this helps a bit to clarify
